# Tensorflow You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'p' with dtype float

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I was using mnist data to see how tf.train.shuffle_batch works, and I got this error

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'p' with dtype float
>        [[Node: p = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>        [[Node: Slice/_1 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_7_Slice", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

But I did feed a value with dtype float to the 'p' placeholder, so I don't get why I'm getting this error

Here's my code:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('../../MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
img = mnist.train.images
print(type(img))
print(img.shape)
p = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='p')
img_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([tf.slice(p, [np.random.randint(55000), 0], [1, -1])], 9, 130, 100)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    img_b = sess.run(img_batch, feed_dict={p: mnist.train.images})
```

Comment: Are you sure that `mnist.train.images` is a **float** ? The mnist dataset is constituted of images, so an **int** makes more sense. Try to cast it with `tf.cast`.

Comment: Casting with `tf.cast` won' do any good, you can't feed tensors as values for placeholders in `feed_dict`. What type is `mnist.train.images`?

Comment: @Lescurel I did print the type of mnist.train.images and the result is numpy array with dtype float, and I also tried with tf.cast, it didn't work either.

Comment: @GPhilo It's <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: I think GPhilo meant the data type of the elements in the numpy array (you can see this using `mnist.train.images.dtype`)

Comment: @Kathy Wu It's dtype('float32')

Comment: Ah, just ran the code and the error popped up at the line `threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)`. I would recommend looking into `tf.data.Dataset` for multi-threaded input handling instead of using queue runners.

Comment: @Kathy Wu OK, I'll try it, thanks!